# C#: How to pass an object array as an argument

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm new to C# (and every other coding language), and my assignment is to create an array of objects and pass that array as an argument to another method that will display all the elements.

My question is simple and probably dumb. I'm trying to return the array to Main and call the displayAll(). I just don't know what to put inside the parameter braces.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            addnew();
            displayAll(); //how to write object array as argument
        }

        public static object[] addnew()
        {
            int i;
            Console.WriteLine("How many Clients would you like to add? ");
            int size = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Client[] clArray = new Client[size];

                for (i = 0; i < clArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    Client client = new Client();

                    Console.WriteLine($"Client " + (i + 1));
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter First Name: ");
                    client.firstName = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Last Name: ");
                    client.lastName = Console.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Client ID: ");
                    client.clientID = (Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Purchase Amount: ");
                    client.purchase = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


                    clArray[i] = client;

                }
            return clArray;
        }
        public static void displayAll(Client[] x)
        {

            for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                object client = x[i];
                Console.WriteLine(client);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using object where you should be using Client?

Comment: Aa @ronbeyer points out, you should change the return type of `addnew` from `object[]` to `Client[]`. Then, just follow the answers you have received

Comment: Honestly, I just used what visual studio recommended. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your variable into the parenthesis, thus making the call look similar to method declaration. This similarity is why declaring and calling methods both use `()`.

In this case, you could call you first method and pass its return directly into your second via

```
displayAll(addnew());
```

This sends the return value of `addnew` to `displayAll` without saving it to a variable. For debugging and readability, you'll usually want to save to a variable and pass *that* in;

```
var data = addnew();
displayAll(data);
```

Comment: The add new function should also return a typed array instead of a boxed one. Otherwise you'll get an error with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may call the method by using the below code:

```
displayAll(addnew());
```

Comment: This will result in an error regarding type conversions. There is something else that needs to be fixed for this to work.